# Yii2. Реализация модулей

Tags: php, алгоритм, yii2

Как на данном фреймворке можно реализовать вывод кода в определенной позиции. Так делают в популярных CMS. Т.е. пользователь зашел в админку, создал модуль, задал позицию модуля. И на сайте в этой позиции должен появиться модуль.

В голову приходит только одна мысль: в базе у каждого модуля будет поле `position`. И на сайте выводит эти самые модули из этой позиции. Правильно ли так делать?

Comment: что может быть в этом "модуле"? какой-то html код или что-то другое?

Comment: @AlMr, да html код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В целом да. Можно хранить текст модулей в базе данных, передавать нужные модули из контроллеров на нужные вьюхи и в зависимости от позиции выводить модули на вью. Можно так же копнуть в сторону виджетов или компонентов yii2 и сделать чуточку красивее, но здесь всё зависит от того насколько хорошо Вы знаете yii и хотите ли так глубоко углубляться в этой тривиальной задаче.